# Soft clip not working for shaded areas beween curves

Tags: shading, function, tikz-shadings

I've been trying to find a way to shade the area between the curves, but when I try coding in LaTeX with softclip, everything shuts down. I don't know what to do.

This is my code :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2, xmax=5,
    ymin=-5, ymax=10,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north},
    ]

    \addplot[blue, domain=-2:5, samples=100, name path=A] {x^2 - 2*x};
    \addlegendentry{$y = x^2 - 2x$}

    \addplot[red, domain=-2:5, samples=100, name path=B] {4*x - x^2};
    \addlegendentry{$y = 4x - x^2$}

    % Create a path for the shaded region
    \path[name path=zero] (0,0) -- (0,8);

    % Shade the region between the two functions in red
    \addplot[red, fill, opacity=0.3] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:3}] \closedcycle;

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to run your code, I see this message:
`! Package pgfplots Error: 'name path' is undefined. Please load \usetikzlibrary {intersections} or \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}.`

So I did that. I inserted `\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}` in the preamble. Now it seems to work perfectly for me.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-2, xmax=5,
    ymin=-5, ymax=10,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)}, anchor=north},
    ]

    \addplot[blue, domain=-2:5, samples=100, name path=A] {x^2 - 2*x};
    \addlegendentry{$y = x^2 - 2x$}

    \addplot[red, domain=-2:5, samples=100, name path=B] {4*x - x^2};
    \addlegendentry{$y = 4x - x^2$}

    % Create a path for the shaded region
    \path[name path=zero] (0,0) -- (0,8);

    % Shade the region between the two functions in red
    \addplot[red, fill, opacity=0.3] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=0:3}] \closedcycle;

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

as long as this is what you wanted...

[image]

Comment: It is exaclty what I need, I don't know what's missing then. I added \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} and it still doesnt work. Giving me error messages I don't understand. Everything just blocks and shuts down the page I'm working on.

Comment: I guess you could delete any auxiliary files tex has created and retry. sometimes they confuse things